# UnicodeDecodeError 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using PyInstaller 4.2 to compile a project in Python 3.9 using the .spec file. I've done that many times without any problem in the same project but now an exception rises and I don't know why this happens

Message shown in console:

```
58 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.2
58 INFO: Python: 3.9.0
59 INFO: Platform: Windows-10
62 INFO: UPX is not available.
63 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:[...]',
 'D:[...]']
75 INFO: checking Analysis
112 INFO: Building because Analysis-00.toc is bad
112 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
114 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
128 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2471 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\name\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
2472 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\name\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib'
4199 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4291 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4294 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe
4405 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll
4548 INFO: Analyzing AutomateUpdater.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 725, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 672, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "AutomateUpdater.spec", line 6, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['AutomateUpdater.exe'],
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 414, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.run_script(script))
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 303, in run_script
    self._top_script_node = super(PyiModuleGraph, self).run_script(
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1411, in run_script
    contents = fp.read() + '\n'
  File "c:\users\name\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Someone please can tell me what happend?

I've tried the solutions that are shown in similar posts but they didn't worked.

Tanks

Comment: My guess is that it's caused by one of your python source files containing the byte `0x90` which is not a valid start byte in utf8. 
You could check all your .py files and make sure they are saved as utf8 and not some uncommon text encoding or binary content.

Comment: Here's the method where the exception happens. Looks like it tries to guess the correct encoding first, but still got it wrong, since it simply looks for something like `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file to make a guess, and falls back to utf-8. Maybe it's the file `AutomateUpdater.exe`? That would make sense, since the byte `0x90` is not used in most 8-bit text encodings.

https://github.com/ronaldoussoren/modulegraph/blob/e4a51fb920a410643ba74f6eb338f387986482aa/modulegraph/modulegraph.py#L1069

Comment: I've just solved the problem. It was my mistake and I put the wrong file name in the .spec file. I wrote AutomateUpdater.exe instead of the python file name that I wanted to compile. Thank you so much for your help!